# Async React Context getting "cannot be used as a JSX component"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to create a `context` to be used for holding logged in data, but I am facing an issue when trying to use the `provider` whereby my IDE is stating:

> MyContextProvider cannot be used as a JSX component.
>
> Its return type  Promise  is not a valid JSX element.
>
> Type  Promise  is missing the following properties from type  ReactElement<any, >any> : type, props, key

**MyContext**

```
import React, {createContext, useCallback, useState} from 'react';
// Other imports

const initialContext = {
  loggedIn: false,
  user: undefined,
  handleLoggedIn: () => {},
  handleUser: () => {},
  ...
};

export const MyContext = createContext(initialContext);

const getLoggedIn = async () => await new UserService().isLoggedIn();
const getUser = async () => await new UserService.getProfile().then(u => u.Data);

export const MyContextProvider = async (props: any) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(await getLoggedIn());
  const [user, setUser] = useState<ProfileModel>(await getUser());
  // More similar pieces...

  const handleLoggedIn = useCallback(async isLoggedIn => setLoggedIn(isLoggedIn), []);
  const handleUser = useCallback(async userData => setUser(userData), []);
  // More similar pieces...

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{
        loggedIn,
        user,
        handleLoggedIn,
        handleUser
        ...
      }}>
      {props.children}
    </LoggedInContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Usage:
I am actually wrapping some React-Native navigator screens

```
const someStack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => (
  <MyContextProvider>
    <someStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ title: 'Some screen' }}>
        <someStack.Screen name="Home" component={SomeAccountComp} />
        <someStack.Screen name="Orders" component={SomeOrdersComp} options={{title: "My Orders" }} />
    </myAccount.Navigator>
  </LoggedInContextProvider>
);
```

It's at this point that I'm getting the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `async` function in JS returns a Promise.
This is not allowed for React components.

So one possible fix is to provide a default value for the context provider's state and set it once the async function resolves:

```
// no async allowed
const MyContextProvider = ()=>{
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false); // may consider to have a third, "uninitialized" value for initial state
  useEffect(()=>{
     let stillLoaded = true;
     const loadLoggedIn = async ()=>{
        const loggedIn = await getLoggedIn();
        if(stillLoaded) {
           setLoggedIn(loggedIn);
        }
     }
     loadLoggedIn();
     return ()=>{stillLoaded = false};
  }, []);
  // [...]
}
```